# if database id field empty hide text

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to not display text if there is no id # in database field 'types'. If there is a item 'id' in database then the info will be displayed as 'Type: Item type' which is fine.

The problem is that when no id # is in database because no item type selected, then on page appears 'Type:' when I would prefer to show nothing.

The code that displays the text is below.

```
        <? if($this->params->get('item_types', 1) == 1 || ($this->params->get('item_types', 1) == 2 && !empty($this->item->types))){ ?>
    <strong class="label_detailed_item"><?php echo JText::_( 'Type' ); ?></strong> <span class="value_detailed_item"><?php echo implode(" / ",$this->item->types); ?></span><br />
    <? } ?>
```

I have tried changing using below but the text still shows

```
<?php if ( !empty($this->item->types)) echo JText::_( 'Type' ); ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You forgot the `$` in your empty() call... `(!empty($this->....)`

Comment: changed thank you but the '$' was in code I had tried before that didn't work.

Comment: try `!empty($this->item->types)`

Comment: yes left out '->' but I had that before and didn't work.. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Could it be possible that $this->item-types might contain a space character.  That would cause empty() to return FALSE.

If you are looking for an Id and that Id is always an integer, cast to an integer.

```
<?php if ( !empty((integer)$this->item->types)) echo JText::_( 'Type' ); ?>
```